# Regex match only if substring occures once

Tags: python, regex

I have an input of a single string that looks like

```
foo[TAG1][TAG2]
```

where TAG1 and TAG2 are unique predefined set of words and each of them should be used only once.

For example, TAG1 = {A, B, C} and TAG2 = {1, 2, 3}.

The following should match:

- `foo[A][1]`
- `foo[B][3]`
- `foo[2][B]`

The following shouldn't match:

- `foo[A][A]`
- `foo[1][3]`
- `foo[C][B]`
- `foo[C]`
- `foo[23]`

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you write a separate pattern for all 18 combinations/orderings of tags. You might be better off with a non-regex solution.

Comment: and your attempts are?

Comment: Are the tags only one character long, or could be longer?

Comment: Also, should `foo[Z][1]` pass or fail?

Comment: @Kevin, I need this for reddit's automoderator so I thought that it might be possible through regex.

Comment: @glibdud if you are talking about given example then it should fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following pattern:

```
r'(foo(?:(?:\[[A-Z]\]\[\d+\])|(?:\[\d+\]\[[A-Z]\])))'
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kyyl9h/2)

---

Breakdown:

- 1st Capturing Group `(foo(?:(?:\[[A-Z]\]\[\d+\])|(?:\[\d+\]\[[A-Z]\])))`

  - foo matches the characters foo literally (case sensitive)
  - Non-capturing group `(?:(?:\[[A-Z]\]\[\d+\])|(?:\[\d+\]\[[A-Z]\]))`

    - 1st Alternative `(?:\[[A-Z]\]\[\d+\])`

      - Non-capturing group `(?:\[[A-Z]\]\[\d+\])` `\[` matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)

        - Match a single character present in the list below `[A-Z]`
        - `A-Z` a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
        - ] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
        - [ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
        - \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        - ] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
    - 2nd Alternative `(?:\[\d+\]\[[A-Z]\])`

      - Non-capturing group `(?:\[\d+\]\[[A-Z]\])`

        - `\[` matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
        - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        - `\]` matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
        - `\[` matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
        - Match a single character present in the list below `[A-Z]`
        - `\]` matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)

Comment: TAG1 and TAG2 are described as "predefined set(s) of words", which leads me to believe that they won't always consist of single letters or digits.

Comment: Yes perhaps @glibdud in any case that should be quite simple to adapt by changing the content between brackets

Comment: Asker also clarified in comments that only the items in the set should match, so for example `foo[Z][1]` should fail.

Comment: hmm hard to give an answer to `match ìtems in a predefined set`... not knowing what they could be. As mentioned above this is simple to adapt. We just need to define a set of characters and replace the contents between brackets @glibdud

Comment: Thank you very much, that works exactly how I need.
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/eaWYcv/1) is the test on some actual tags that I plan to use.

Comment: Great I see you managed yo adapt it @Lenassa ! You're welcome :)

Comment: @Lenassa, but why have you used tag `python` in your question if you need just regex?

Comment: As far as I know, different languages have slightly different syntax, so I thought it would be better to clarify this.

Comment: @Lenassa, then I can recommend you a bit [shorter](https://regex101.com/r/eaWYcv/2) method (which I've used in my answer).

Comment: @OlvinRoght, "foo" in my example could be any UTF-8 string. I definitely should have mentioned that, now when I think about it, sorry :( So, in yatu's regex I can remove "foo" from the beginning and it will work just fine. I managed to adapt your method by replacing "foo" with ".*", but it takes ~10 times more steps to process the same sample.

Comment: @Lenassa, what([1](https://regex101.com/r/eaWYcv/3), [2](https://regex101.com/r/eaWYcv/4)) is the problem?

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I mean [yatu's](https://regex101.com/r/eaWYcv/5) is only 228 steps while [yours](https://regex101.com/r/eaWYcv/6) is 2516.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, [yours](https://regex101.com/r/eaWYcv/12) is catching "foo[TAG1]bar[TAG2]" kind of string. Also, I've [updated](https://regex101.com/r/eaWYcv/14) yatu's version a little bit, so it's quite short now too.

Comment: @Lenassa, I surrender. Your last is the best possible.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, still thank you a lot, without your contribution I most likely would have just used the very first one.

Answer (score 0):

**Imports:**

```
import re
```

**Input data:**

```
rules = {
    "TAG1": {"A", "B", "C"},
    "TAG2": {"1", "2", "3"}
}

template = "foo[TAG1][TAG2]"

test_strings = ["foo[A][1]", "foo[B][3]", "foo[2][B]", "foo[A][A]", "foo[1][3]", "foo[C][B]", "foo[C]", "foo[23]"]
```

**Code:**

```
compiled_template = template[:]

for k, v in rules.items():
    if k in template:
        compiled_template = compiled_template.replace(f"[{k}]", f"(?=.*\[({'|'.join(v)})\])")

for string in test_strings:
    if re.match(compiled_template, string):
        print(string)
```

**Output:**

```
foo[A][1]
foo[B][3]
foo[2][B]
```